# Pluggable pages in a Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modularity

I'm developing a Spring application which needs to support pluggable modules - add the JAR to the classpath and it will automatically find and load the module's Spring application context XML. This part is already working.

The problem right now is figuring out a way for the modules to provide custom JSP pages. Each module will require a configuration page, which contains form fields specific to that module.

How can I use Spring MVC to implement such pluggable pages? It should work something like so, that the module's JAR file contains the configuration page (as JSP) and its Spring MVC controller, which the surrounding application will then include into the rest of the application (maybe as a JSP fragment inside the application's page template).

If this cannot be done with Spring MVC and JSP, then what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `ResourceBundleViewResolver` config to each pluggable module (not sure if having multiple resolvers will work or not, but it allows you to define views via the classpath, not specific locations.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/view.html.

If having multiple resolvers in your modules don't work, then try `ResourceBundleViewResolver` in the main app config, and then have all pluggable modules follow the same view location setup internally to the JARs.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working. It seems that it's not possible to use JSP files which are inside JARs. Using Freemarker or Velocity it should be possible: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?71958-Spring-MVC-get-the-jsp-from-a-jar